# How to remove properties from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array like this

```
[
    '0',
    '1',
    '2',
    arg0: '0',
    arg1: '1',
    arg2: '2'
]
```

and I would like to remove the "properties" with a name in order to get this

```
[
    '0',
    '1',
    '2'
]
```

I do not know the names of the properties up front, how can I achieve this?

Comment: how do you generate the array?

Comment: why do you add properties to an array in the first place?

Comment: This "array" is provided to me by a third party library

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [0,1]
arr.arg0 = 0
arr.arg1 = 1
arr.arg2 = 2
arr.push(2)

console.log(Array.from(arr))
```

if you would like to remove the properties to avoid allocating a new array and mutate it instead you could get the keys and slice it at the length to get none numerical keys

```js
var arr = [0,1,2]
arr.arg0 = 0
arr.arg1 = 1
arr.arg2 = 2

const props = Object.keys(arr).slice(arr.length)
props.forEach(prop => delete arr[prop])

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: They don’t know the names of the properties up front.

Comment: don't mather, the names will be removed, Array.from will read the length and take all from 0 to n

Comment: `Object.keys(arr).slice(arr.length)` this would fail for sparse arrays: `["a", , "c"]` will have two keys - `0` and `2` but the `arr.length` is `3`

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr = [0,1,2]
arr.arg0 = 0
arr.arg1 = 1
arr.arg2 = 2
arr = [...arr]
```

Answer (score 0):

Old fashion way here

```js
const arr = [0,1,2];
arr.arg0 = 0;
arr.arg1 = 1;
arr.arg2 = 2;

// Define new arr
const newArr = [];
// Loop and rebuild
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) newArr.push(arr[i]);

// print new array
console.log(newArr);

// Try to access property
console.log(newArr.arg2);
```

Comment: Seems easier to `.map()` using the identity function or `.filter()` with an empty predicate. And even simpler by just doing a shallow copy using `.splice()` - these all return a new array without needing to do an explicit loop.

Comment: Well there is "Old fashion way here" in the header) Of course you can use all this add-ons, but I'm showing pure native iteration method. And of course if you need to iterate arrays with millions of values, this simple `for` way will be fastest one imho

Comment: What makes `.splice` not new fashioned? It's been used for cloning arrays (and array-likes) for a VERY long time. How much longer until it becomes "old fashioned"?

Comment: if you go for optimization then cache `arr.length` and compare `i < len`

Comment: @Endless this optimisation hasn't been needed since IE8 or so.

Comment: Maybe i'm too old school :P

Comment: @VLAZ well I'm talking about `.map()` and `.filter()`, which technically also do internal loops... I don't know how to clone arrays with `.splice()`